# Как сделать так, чтобы если avp.com ADDKEY выводит что-нибудь, то продолжать перебор, иначе — выполнять 'pause'?

Tags: windows, cmd, bat

Пытаюсь уже несколько часов написать `.bat`, как мне надо. Пишу `.bat` для добавления ключей в `Kaspersky`:

```
@ECHO OFF
title Author: Ivan Chernovalov
prompt $S
C:
CD "C:\Program Files\Kaspersky Lab\Kaspersky Internet Security 2012\"
@for %%B in ("D:\a\*.key") do @ECHO ON & avp.com ADDKEY %%B &@ECHO OFF & pause
@ECHO OFF
pause
```

и где `avp.com ADDKEY %%B` при не удаче выводится сообщение на экран типа:

```
Error: Cannot add key file 'D:\\KIS12_2012-10-28_x5_12E2307F.key': your license has expired
```

а при удаче ничего не выводится затем (в моём .bat код которого приведён выше) происходит `pause`. Это рассчитано на то, чтобы я не выполнял однотипные операции по перебору ключа. Но! В данной реализации я должен смотреть на результат и если вижу что-то типа:

```
Для продолжения нажмите любую клавишу . . .
Error: Cannot add key file 'D:\a\KIS12_2013-01-09_11E80E86.key': your license has     expired
```

то нажать Enter, а если вижу что-то типа:

```
Для продолжения нажмите любую клавишу . . .
Для продолжения нажмите любую клавишу . . .
```

то есть `avp.com ADDKEY %%B` ни чего не выводит, то мой ключ добавился и можно закрывать `KISKeyAdder.bat`, но ключей может быть громадное количество (200+ шт) и даже нажимать <kbd>enter</kbd> столько надоедает!  Вот суть: помогите написать код так, чтобы если `avp.com ADDKEY` выводит что-нибудь, то продолжать перебор, иначе  — выполнять `'pause'`.

Даже книгу Р. Станек'а для этого скачал, но придумать не могу, а всё книгу читать не хочу, но там есть:

> команда1 | команда2 - перенаправление
> вывода команды 1 в команду 2

Но я не понял, как этим воспользоваться... Пожалуйста, помогите.

Answer (score 2):

Совет от ТП Kaspersky LAB:

Активация через командную строку:

- Сохраните ключевой файл в корень диска C:\
- Нажмите кнопку ''Пуск'' в левом нижнем углу экрана -> выберите пункт ''Выполнить'' -> в открывшемся окне введите команду cmd и нажмите ''ОК'' - откроется окно командной строки
- Откройте папку C:\Program Files\Kaspersky Lab\Kaspersky Internet Security 2013\ -> найдите файл avp.com, выделите его мышкой и перетащите прямо в окно командной строки -> при этом в командной строке должен отобразиться полный путь к файлу avp.com
- В этой же строке поставьте пробел и допишите команду addkey C:\ИМЯ_КЛЮЧА.key (между addkey и C:\ тоже должен быть пробел)

Пожалуйста, обратите внимание, что, если на настройки Антивируса установлен пароль, то в команде активации после имени ключа.key надо поставить пробел и дописать password=Ваш_Пароль

А то что вы просите:

- подбор из несортированной кучи ключей, это или глупость(так как у вас нет порядка в "королевстве")
- или преступление (так как вероятно, ключи не ваши, и вы нарушаете лицензионное законодательство)

А при обслуживаниии машин в сети действует ещё правило "превышения количества установленных лицензий" - как будете решать эту проблему?

- В практическом аспекте вопрос решаемый, но глупый - (поэтому решения не дам, читайте и учитесь, думаю тогда желание заниматься решением ТАКИХ проблем отпадёт само-сабой)
- В теоретическо-экспериментальном (для вопросов тестирования и обучения) здесь не место для таких провокаций. Вам на станичку ТП или форум производителя по данному продукту. Либо на портал хака и вареза. ВЫБИРАТЬ ВАМ!!!

Comment: А если бы это был не avp.com то вы не можете мне подсказать как решить такую "элементарную" задачу как "если программа возвращает строку в CMD то действие 1 иначе действие 2"!???

Answer (score 1):

Тебе надо обрабатывать события в зависимости от переменной errorlevel в которую должны писаться значения в зависимости от удачи/неудачи операции. Подробней не посмотреть, я сейчас не в виндовс.